# Typescript mix a generic with defaults and/or infer keys from another generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm working on a websocket implementation that uses JSON-RPC as a way of communication with our backend.

For now i have a WebSocket class that exposes a subscribe Method and a post Method to the user. Said post method should be used to send calls to the backend as well as Subscribe to events on the backend (which in turn is a post - method: Subscribe, params: {topic: the topic}.

to get it typesafe the class uses two generics:

`class WS<TEvents, TMethods>`

`TEvents` is then used to subscribe events on the frontend, `TMethods` are the known methods than can be sent to the backend (where there is definitely a method: Subscribe/Unsubscribe)

The issue with this is that someone who wanted to subscribe to said events needs to subscribe to the event but also post it to the backend at the moment:

```
// given we have following types:
TEvent = {
    "my-topic": InterfaceOfTheTopic
    "another-topic": InterfaceOfTheOtherTopic
}

TMethod = {
    Subscribe: (params: {topic: "my-topic" | "another-topic"}) => void;
}

const ws = new Socket<TEvent, TMethod>()

ws.subscribe("my-topic", subScriptionHandler);
ws.post("Subscribe", {topic: "my-topic"});
```

obviously it would be better if the WebSocket class would do it in one go.

eg having in the websocket class:

```
async subscribe() {
    await this.post("Subscribe", {topic: event})
    return super.subscribe(event, callback);
}
```

This would basically require something like

```
type BaseMethods<EVENTS> {
    Subscribe: (params: {topic: keyof EVENTS}) => void
}

class WS<TEvents, TMethods & BaseMethods<TEvents>>
```

I just can't wrap my head around it. I understand that generics are basically just metadata so i'd be fine if i could at least specify that methods Subscribe and Unsubscribe are definitely known by the backend (and basically would be okay with topic: string) but i couldn't manage to get it to work so far.

Is this even possible to use GenericA as a parameter for GenericB or mix GenericB with a baseType that uses said first generic?

[minimal implementation just to showcase workflow - no websocket logc](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-rgb-tojxos?file=/src/WS.ts)

Comment: please provide  minimum reproducible example

Comment: added some code to showcase the final workflow

Comment: So your main issue is that you need to constrain `TMethods` [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/wgQe1m); but you are using a lot of generic conditional types and the compiler doesn't understand those very well, so inside `WS.subscribe` there's no way for the compiler to figure out that `{topic: event}` matches ` MethodParamsIfExists<TMethods, "Subscribe">`, so you'll need a type assertion.  If you don't want type assertions then you'll probably need a significant refactor to avoid conditional types, like [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/WY3dxN).

Comment: Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (To notify me of your reply, please mention @jcalz)

Comment: oh my... really didn't think of just adding that constrain... was a bit done after setting this up.

i will give your solution a try later when i'm back at it. Still thank you already for your suggestions!